# what method is used by httpSession for session management in Java

Tags: java, session

I read lot of articles which says that there are different ways to manage the session like cookies, hidden form fields, url rewriting and jsessionId.

But when I do
 `HttpSession session = request.getSession();`

Which method is actually used internally?

Comment: This is very difficult to answer if we don't know which language or library you are using.

Comment: I thought httpSession is available in Java only (sorry that I forgot to mention it). I updated question.

Comment: Might be, but there are so many languages and frameworks out there. And "httpsession" is not really a unique name. Always tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [servlet 2.4 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-2.4-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/servlet-2_4-fr-spec.pdf):

> Session tracking through HTTP cookies is the most used session
>   tracking mechanism and is required to be supported by all servlet
>   containers... To fulfill this requirement, Web containers commonly
>   support the URL rewriting mechanism.

Comment: The part in ellipses is an important part of this specification, and by omitting it you are giving a completely false impression of what it says.

Comment: You should edit it then, @EJP, if you feel it's an *important part of the specification*; OP certainly didn't

Answer (score 0):

Basically the session tracking (i.e. to keep the user interaction and sending the data ) can be maintained by 4 ways like HttpSession,cookies,hidden field and URL rewriting.

It depends on your requirement , which it needs to use.

If you are using HttpSession then you need to go for

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
```

As Cookies are client side.

Hidden fields are the form data you need to send to by request to servlet.

URL rewriting is used for sending the data using `href` or any link (usally `GET` method).

Session is used for secure and state full transaction.

```
Which method is actually used internally?
```

Its recommended to use `HttpSession` , if you want to track the request data over the application, until unless you invalidate that session. Jsessionid is a part of `HttpSession`. Internally Session is using unique `Jsessionid` for each session you are creating.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that it doesn't depend on Java. It depends on the specific servlet container you are using and possibly the browser as well. If the brower won't accept cookies for example the container may be forced back to using URL rewriting.